# "PUT" request gets sent via AJAX, but no data component transferred

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Through AJAX your supposed to have support for the "PUT" and "DELETE" requests. I have a form that sends data via the "PUT" request and the server acknowledges it but no parameters get sent. The same result happens for the "delete" request. If I change to "post" it works fine. **IE 9, Firefox, and Chrome** all produce the same result. The put and delete requests are being sent but with no data.

```
$("#startButton").click(function(){
                $.ajax({url:"http://localhost:8084/Project/servlet",
                    data:parseFormData("simulatorForm"),
                    cache: "false",
                    dataType: "text",
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",                
                    type:"put",
                    error:function(xhr){alert(xhr.status + xhr.statusText);} });
            });
```

**NOTE:** If I change to "post" this works fine. All parameters in my form get transmitted. I tried this in IE, Chrome, and Mozilla Firefox.

I tried doing it in pure javascript but I get the exact same results.

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
           xmlhttp.open("PUT","http://localhost:8084/UtilityDashboard/SensorSimulator",true);
           xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           xmlhttp.send(parseFormData("simulatorForm"));
```

Comment: Already answered :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers

Comment: What is the problem with `get` or `post` mehtod

Comment: @Archer That question is about submitting requests through forms. Given the answer to that users post, this is suppose to work. XMLHTTPRequest is suppose to be the work around to regular form submission.

Comment: @jhonraymos Nothing but if it worked it's neater on the server-side. I'm using apache tomcat. Using post for updating and creating would mean adding more if statements to the same method.

Comment: Could you also provide `parseFormData()`?  Everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What web-server are you using?  Special note about PUT/DELETE requests:

By default IIS 6 does not support PUT and DELETE verbs. To enable this, you need to add a wildcard mapping to the virtual directory of your application, this is as simple as clicking the insert button next to Wildcard application maps in your site or virtual directory properties in IIS Manager and entering the path to aspnet_isapi.dll.

Comment: I'm using apache tomcat. It has support for PUT and Delete. The put and delete handlers get called with these requests but the data is blank.

Comment: Just checked my browser requests. The data is making its way out so this must be a server-side issue.

Comment: Great news.  You should add a comment when the server issue gets resolved.  Or at least I think that would be helpful.